# Alternative to onblur/onchange in select

Tags: javascript, select, dom-events

I am trying to find a way to run a JavaScript function when a user selects an option in an HTML `select` box, regardless of whether this option was already selected. So `onchange` is out of the question.

The problem with using `onblur` is that (in Chrome and Safari, at least) the event is not triggered until the user clicks another element. This can also prove annoying if the user focuses on the select, then clicks away without choosing an option, in which case I do not want the event to be triggered.

I was able to get some success by giving each of the options an `onmouseup` handler, but this only works in Firefox, as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

Comment: @Barmar - No. I would guess that only Firefox supports click events for `option` elements. I will mention, however, that I haven't tested any of this in IE.

Comment: An ugly solution would be to make `selectedIndex=-1` whenever `onfocus`, so you can safely listen to `onchange`. That would be annoying for keyboard users, but if you assume your clients don't care about what they previously selected, this may worth a test.

Comment: @Passerby - I had considered doing something like this, but I didn't think to use `onfocus`. What I am doing now is making the first option `select one:` and setting the `selectedIndex` to 0 `onfocus`. It seems to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody has bothered to answer this, I'll post a generic version of my code:

```html
<select id="mySelect" onfocus="this.selectedIndex=0;" onchange="userDidSomething(event)">
    <option>Choose one:</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

The JavaScript:

```javascript
function userDidSomething(event) {
    // Your Code Here.
}
```

Comment: This will stop the browser from loading if javascript isn't turned on. I would think that you could use onChange like this:

```var s = document.getElementById("mySelect");
s.attachEvent("onchange", function() {
    // function here
});```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var s = document.getElementById("mySelect");
s.attachEvent("onchange", function() {
    // function here
});
```

Comment: He said, he don't want `onchange`

Comment: My apologies. Is an event listener not a possibility? Probably not if the trouble is an old Internet Explorer.